# Multiple [program:laravel-worker] on the same server with Supervisor

Tags: laravel

I have a server with multiple projects that will be using Laravel queues for sending emails

I saw how to add one [program:laravel-worker] for an individual project, but how do we add more than one?

Example:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

This is for **one** project, I'm not sure how to add more than one?

(example: app2.com, app3.com, etc)

Comment: Just name it program:laravel-worker-app1…3 and change path in command and log

Comment: @Maksim I tried that but when I run: 
sudo supervisorct1 start laravel-worker-app1:*

that code returns: laravel-worker-app1: ERROR (spawn error)

Comment: @Maksim I figured it out! I had to change "sqs" to "database" in the "command" section!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, the first thing is to change "sqs" to "database" in the "command" line

Next, you do the following for multiple:

```
[program:laravel-worker-app1]
command=php /home/*username*/app1.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/*username*/app1.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

```
[program:laravel-worker-app2]
command=php /home/*username*/app2.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/*username*/app2.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

```
[program:laravel-worker-app3]
command=php /home/*username*/app3.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/*username*/app3.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Then run the following commands in terminal (this is in AlmaLinux):

```
sudo supervisorctl update
```

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

```
supervisorctl start all
```

Then check they are all running with:

```
supervisorctl status
```